# How can we pass variables from one method to another in the same class without taking the help of parent class?

Tags: java, variables, methods

let's take a simple program like this :

```
public class Dope
{
public void a()
{
   String t = "my";
  int k = 6;
}
public void b()
{
    System.out.println(t+" "+k);/*here it shows an error of not recognizing any variable*/
}
public static void main(String Ss[])
 {

 }   
}
```

although i can correct it by just resorting to this way :

```
  public class Dope
{
String t;
  int k ;
public void a()
{
    t = "my";
   k = 6;
}
public void b()
{
    System.out.println(t+" "+k);
}
 public static void main(String Ss[])
 {

 }   
}
```

but i wanted to know if there's any way in my former program to pass the variables declared in `method a` to `method b` without taking the help of parent class ?

Comment: They're called method parameters.

Comment: thanks a lot, excuse my poor grasp for technical terminology

Comment: No, I mean the technique that you can use is method parameters. You'll need to modify `b()` to take parameters of course.

Comment: Just define parameters for your method b and pass t and k? That's easiest Java, please try to learn Java first, by reading a book or doing a tutorial!

Comment: Learn how to declare method parameters and pass them when you call methods: see [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Comment: @ThomasBöhm... well am on that path now itself....

Comment: @Jesper, thanks i will check that out

Comment: @Kayaman...excuse me again...i  now get you

Comment: https://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/68891104.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare b method with two parameters, as following example:

```
public class Dope
{
    public void a()
    {
        String t = "my";
        int k = 6;

        b(t, k);
    }

    public void b(String t, int k)
    {
        System.out.println(t+" "+k);
    }

    public static void main(String Ss[])
    {

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the signature of your method from `b()` to `b(String t,int k)`

```
public void b(String t, int k)
{
    System.out.println(t+" "+k);
}
```

and give a call to `b(String t,int k)` from method `a()`

By using these method parameters you need not change the scope of the variables.

> But remember when ever you pass something as a parameter in Java it is
>   passed as call by value.